# MySQL substring between two strings

Tags: mysql, string, function, indexing, substring

I need a hand to solve a problem with my column field.
I need to extract the string in between these two different "patterns" of strings for example:

> [...string] contract= 1234567890123350566076070666 issued= [string
>   ...]

I want to extract the string in between 'contract=' and 'issued='

At the present moment I'm using

```
SELECT substring(substring_index(licence_key,'contract=',-1),1,40) FROM table
```

The problem is that this string in between doesn't have always 40 characters so it's not fixed length and so the data that comes before and after that. It's a volatile data.

Do you known how I can handle that?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Just use `substring_index()` twice:

```
SELECT substring_index(substring_index(licence_key, 'contract=', -1),
                       'issued=', 1)
FROM table;
```

Comment: That's clever, indeed... I was trying to migrate a unnormalized DB on ver. 5.5 to 5.7 (I'm a little skeptical about ver. 8). It had a column that has json string, but luckily, the structure of json is consistent throughout the table. This saved me a lot of CPU, I didn't want to get all the data into a script and then insert each row into new table.

Comment: BTW, I'm aware of json support in mySQL ver above 5.6. I just don't see the point of storing JSON in a relational DB unless you have no other choice or if you don't have to ever do a lookup in that column to reduce the complexity of DB.

Answer (score 1):

If this string does not match then give the total result.

If you want to replace then you can use like this.

```
UPDATE questions set question= REPLACE(question, '<xml></xml>', '') WHERE question like '%<xml>%';

UPDATE questions set question= REPLACE(question, substring_index(substring_index(question, '<xml>', -1), '</xml>', 1), '') WHERE question like '%<xml>%';
```