# How do I get the values ​between these fields with format?

Tags: mysql

I am doing a db migration I need to pass data from db1 to db2. I am getting a sql query result similar to this. Formats like  and [:es] or  represent the language.

```
name
------------
<!--:es-->Nombre<!--:--><!--:en-->Name<!--:-->
<!--:es-->Ciudad<!--:--><!--:en-->City<!--:-->
<!--:es-->Pais<!--:--><!--:en-->Country<!--:-->
<!--:es-->Email<!--:--><!--:en-->Email<!--:-->
<!--:es-->Telefono<!--:--><!--:en-->Phone<!--:-->
[:es]Apodo[:en]Nikname[:]
[:es]Tipo[:en]Type[:]
[:es]Categoria[:en]Category[:]
[:es]Distribuidor[:en]Distributor[:]
Value 1
Value 2
Value 3
```

Some data comes with format `<!--:es-->Field<!--:es-->...`

Others comes with format `[:es]Apodo[:en]Nikname[:]`

And some with no special format. For example `Value 1`, `Value 2` and `Value 3`.

I need only the name, without any special delimiter.  Any idea how to achieve this.

The expected result is

```
name
------------
Nombre
Ciudad
Pais
Email
Telefono
Apodo
Tipo
Categoria
Distribuidor
Value 1
Value 2
Value 3
```

Update

My sql version is

```
mysql -V 
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Comment: Can you use MySQL version 8 or higher?  Also please include the desired result based on your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I got to handle this case in the following way

With the help of [case when](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html), first I identify the type of format, using the [locate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) function, once the route is identified with the help of the [substring_index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function is excluded the text that I do not require and I only get the text that is relevant to me

```
case
    when
        locate('[:]', name) > 0
    then
        substring_index(substring_index(name, '[:es]', -1),'[:en]', 1)
    else
        substring_index(substring_index(name, '<!--:es-->', -1),'<!--:-->', 1)
end names
```

I add a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38c2d2/5) to test

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28432157/615274) was useful in this case