# How to extract values from multiple tables in SQL an and IN condition?

Tags: sql, alasql

I have three tables with data for which I want to get a combined overview created using an SQL query.
The first table "Epics" conists of a column with key values and another column which contains a list of keys.
The second and third tables contain a status for each of these keys.

The tables can be illustrated like follows:

```
Epics
  Key      Sub-Tasks
+--------+----------------+
| MCR-1  | MCR-21, MCR-31 |
+--------+----------------+
| MCR-2  | MCR-22, MCR-32 |
+--------+----------------+
| MCR-3  | MCR-23, MCR-33 |
+--------+----------------+

QM Sub-Tasks
  Key      Status
+--------+-------------+
| MCR-21 | DONE        |
+--------+-------------+
| MCR-22 | OPEN        |
+--------+-------------+
| MCR-23 | IN PROGRESS |
+--------+-------------+


E3 Sub-Tasks
  Key      Status
+--------+--------------+
| MCR-31 | NOT RELEVANT |
+--------+--------------+
| MCR-32 | DONE         |
+--------+--------------+
| MCR-33 | OPEN         |
+--------+--------------+
```

Now I created the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT epics.'Key' AS 'MCR-Key'
    qm.'Status' AS 'QM Status'
    e3.'Status' As 'E3 Status'
FROM T3 epics
    LEFT JOIN T1 qm ON (qm.'Key' IN epics.'Sub-Tasks')
    LEFT JOIN T2 e3 ON (e3.'Key' IN epics.'Sub-Tasks')
```

However, by using this statement, only the first row contains the status values of tables two and three, but all subsequent rows only contain the epic's key:

```
Output
  MCR-Key   QM Status      E3 Status
+---------+--------------+-----------+
| MCR-1   | NOT RELEVANT | DONE      |
+---------+--------------+-----------+
| MCR-2   |              |           |
+---------+--------------+-----------+
| MCR-3   |              |           |
+---------+--------------+-----------+
```

Any idea why this is the case and how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Please tag RDBMS that you use.

Comment: I must admit that I do not know what is used under the hood. I suppose MySQL or PostgreSQL. I am just using a macro plugin (called Table Transformer) for Confluence where the results from different filters (-> tables) can be aggregated and transformed into user-defined views.

Comment: Since you don't know which RDBMS you are using, logic is in the answer. Just adapt to you.

Answer (score 0):

I must 1st split string from `epics.sub-tasks` and left part to join with `QM sub-tasks` table, right to join with `E3 sub-tasks` table.

The answer will be:

```
SELECT 
     e.[Key] 'MCR-Key',
     q.[Status] 'QM Status',
     e3.[status] 'E3 Status'
FROM Epics e
LEFT JOIN [QM Sub-tasks] Q 
       ON Q.[Key] = SUBSTRING(e.[sub-tasks], 0, CHARINDEX(',', e.[sub-tasks]))
LEFT JOIN [E3 Sub-tasks] E3
       ON E3.[Key] = right(e.[sub-tasks], charindex(',', reverse(e.[sub-tasks])) - 2)
```

Here you can check my demo on [DB<>FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=562d5d1d449b415e82ff7eefbe371529)

And .... I must say something more

### NEVER NAME YOUR COLUMN WITH RESERVED WORDS

and do **NOT** use hyphen (-) into column name

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It seems like the system is definitely not MSSQL ;-)
Isn't there a more generic solution for the JOINs? I am asking, since the number of sub-tasks can be also more than two for a given epic. I just wanted to keep the example simple.

Comment: In any way, you must split string from sub-tasks from epics and join to how many tables you have. If you are using MySQL, you can achieve with `substring_index()` check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431268/mysql-substring-between-two-strings/28432157). With this, you will get as many columns as you have strings separated by commas.